# magento 2.2.5: Adding Custom Attribute to Customer Edit Form in Admin

Tags: adminhtml, customer-attribute, magento-2.2.5

I am trying to add a custom attribute using below code but its not working -

```
     
    namespace A2bizz\Customer\Setup;
    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;



    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {

        /**
         * @var CustomerSetupFactory
         */
        protected $customerSetupFactory;

        /**
         * @var AttributeSetFactory
         */
        private $attributeSetFactory;

        /**
         * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
         * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
            AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
        ) {
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
            $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        }

        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
                    $setup->startSetup();


            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'a2bizz_attribute2', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Custom Attribute2',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'a2bizz_attribute2')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);

            $attribute->save();
            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

I check the backend entries in database , the entry of attribute is added to the tables , `eav_attribute` and `customer_eav_attribute`

but still it is not showing in edit form in admin section.

I also run below commands -

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with following. This is working for me to add custom attribute -

> A2bizz/Example/Setup/InstallData.php

```
namespace A2bizz\Example\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

    private $_eavSetupFactory;
    private $_attributeRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository $attributeRepository
    )
    {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->_attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    }

    public function install( ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context )
    {

        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // add customer_attribute to customer
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_attribute');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_attribute', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Custom Customer Attribute',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'sort_order' => '200'
        ]
    );

    // allow customer_attribute attribute to be saved in the specific areas
    $attribute = $this->_attributeRepository->get('customer', 'customer_attribute');
    $setup->getConnection()
    ->insertOnDuplicate(
        $setup->getTable('customer_form_attribute'),
        [
            ['form_code' => 'adminhtml_customer', 'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId()]
        ]
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: @amit_game did it work ?

Comment: yes,  it worked for me